# Chrome Web Inspector: Find and Replace

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Is there a "Find and Replace" function in Chrome Web Inspector? If it exists, where can I find it? I'm using Chrome 26.0.1410.64, if it matters.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Nothing built in natively. There is a [`Search and Replace`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-and-replace/bldchfkhmnkoimaciljpilanilmbnofo) plugin that might help **if you want to change text in the input fields**.

Alternatively if you want to search and replace in the `HTML` you could *Right Click* → *Edit as HTML* the `<body>` in the *DevTools Elements Panel* select all the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, paste into your favourite editor, make the change there and paste it back.

Comment: The [Search and Replace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-and-replace/bldchfkhmnkoimaciljpilanilmbnofo) plugin lets you replace text anywhere on the page, including the HTML.

Comment: Search and Replace plugin is not working on the HTML content

Comment: Hi Evan, Search and Replace does work on the HTML of the page if you uncheck `Input Fields Only`. If this still doesn't work, feel free to [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/forgetso/search-replace/issues).

Comment: @EvanCamilleri for an example of replacing HTML, see [this video](https://i.imgur.com/vgXUm0G.gif)

Answer (score 71):

***Taken from [this page](http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-replace-text-in-web-pages/29080/) at labnol.org***

While you are on the web page, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Mac to open the Console window inside Chrome Developer tools. Now enter the following commands to replace all occurrences of the word ABC with XYZ.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/ABC/g, "XYZ")
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML.replace(/ABC/g, "XYZ")
```

Comment: Nice one. Not perfect though, since it only affects content in the body of the page.

Comment: This is a great automation for people who need to replace sensitive information in screenshots for bug reports, software documentation, etc. Instead of blurring/blocking parts in screenshots with image editing software or already sophisticated "Inspect Element -> Edit inner HTML" with the browser's developer tools, this is the power workflow for those who need to find & replace numerous instances or numerous similar but different elements (i.e. all money transactions, prices, etc) which can be well handled with regular expressions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To show your redactions transparently you may use the unicode "full block" █ (U+2588). With the help of RegEx you can leave the amount of original characters, or reduce it to a uniform length (to give even less clues about the original content).

Comment: @porg Would you mind supplying how to do that via a dedicated answer?

Comment: @Cfomodz I don't think thats correct within the honor system of StackOverflow. davem answered and linked to the source from where s/he learned about it. My comment is merely a variant of it. But as the answer was set to edit-able I could add one paragraph with the example of how to replace with a RegEx to redaction symbols.

Comment: @davem Are you ok with adding this variation as the last paragraph to your answer?

Comment: To both: As the response may take some time and @Cfomodz would surely benefit from a quick answer I add it now. Feel free to remove again.

Comment: @Cfomodz I could not edit this answer here. Always got the error message "editing queue full". So eventually posted it into as a [standalone answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71125808/199400) which explicitly references davem 's answer. Thanks again davem on this occasion!

Answer (score 2):

#### How to show redactions explicitly

Requested by @Cfomodz this my answer builds on the [answer of @davem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38492147/199400):

> While you are on the web page, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Mac to open the Console window inside Chrome Developer tools.

With the help of RegEx you can leave the amount of original characters or even better reduce it to a uniform length (to give even less clues about the original content) with a visible redaction symbol like the unicode "full block" █ (U+2588). For example to redact all email addresses in the body of the HTML use:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/[A-Za-z.-]+@[A-Za-z.-]+/g, "███@██████.███")
```

Check out my [RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/jslyEg/1) to see & try this live.

Answer (score -3):

For search and replace in a file in Sources panel you can use shortcut Ctrl+f

Comment: I can only SEARCH using that, but not replace. maybe it was removed in later versions? using Version 49.0.2612.0 dev-m (64-bit)

Comment: Why has this answer not been deleted?

Comment: This is an attempt to answer and should not be deleted [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/35263831).